# Unity script runs in editor but fails to build

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, compiler-errors, unity-editor

I am using Unity 2019.2.10f1 and have encountered a weird bug when trying to build the game. Error message I get is:

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StaticEditorFlags' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I tried to reimport all, and I definitely have UnityEditor use directive for that script.

The following code is used to mark objects as static for optimization purposes and is only executed from the Editor:

```
    private StaticEditorFlags staticFlags = StaticEditorFlags.ContributeGI | StaticEditorFlags.OccluderStatic | StaticEditorFlags.BatchingStatic | StaticEditorFlags.NavigationStatic | StaticEditorFlags.OffMeshLinkGeneration | StaticEditorFlags.ReflectionProbeStatic;

    public void StaticLock()
    {
        lockChanges = true;

        Transform renderRoot = transform.Find("Renders");
        Transform collidersRoot = transform.Find("Colliders");

        if (renderRoot != null)
        {
            int count = renderRoot.childCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                GameObjectUtility.SetStaticEditorFlags(renderRoot.GetChild(i).gameObject, staticFlags);
        }
        if (collidersRoot != null)
        {
            int count = collidersRoot.childCount;
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                GameObjectUtility.SetStaticEditorFlags(collidersRoot.GetChild(i).gameObject, staticFlags);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**First**, `UnityEditor` libraries are not included in the builds, so you should get that error.

**But** in order to not include that script to builds you should put that script in a folder called `Editor`, so Unity will automatically remove scripts inside that folder from builds.

You can create `Editor` folders everywhere. everything inside will be ignored.